# how to change DNS out side hosting user area

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, dns-hosting

Hosting company banned me because of my nationality
i can't access my hosting account and change website DNS is there any method to do that out side hosting user area? i lost my access to account and can't change nameservers

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **it is not possible to change the DNS settings of a domain where you don't manage the Nameservers(NS) which the domain points to**.

If your domain name (**gTLD.**) or your called "registrar" isn't the same as your hosting provider, you can still change the nameservers records (**NS**) with your current registrar in order to manage your DNS records from another server which mustn't be related to your hosting provider and by doing this so, being able to manage DNS domain records. Also, you can with your registrar opt to them (your registrar) to manage your own domain DNS and with this also change your DNS settings too.

If any of this works also you can still opt to contact your current registrar and deal with them for **requesting a domain transfer to another registrar**. Please note that in order to do this you must have an Authorization code(EPP) and an unlocked domain name for transfer.

Please refer to [How to Transfer a Domain - WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Transfer-a-Domain)